# Allow DataGridView column headers to scroll away

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, scroll

Is it possible to make `DataGridView` column headers scroll out of view along with other rows when the grid is scrolled down? I.e. not to keep them visible at all times?

Is there a property in `DataGridView` which would allow this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any design-time property you could set, but maybe you could do something like this? *(Not tested, not sure how well it will perform.)*

```
    private void dataGridView1_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ScrollOrientation == ScrollOrientation.VerticalScroll)
            dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersVisible = (e.NewValue == 0);
    }
```